# Mongo Memory Server Instance creation failed

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mongo-memory-server

I'm writing a test case for API in NodeJs using the mongo memory server and Jest. Whenever trying to create a memory database for test data, it throws an error saying Mongo Memory Instance Failed.

Been trying to resolve this issue from last few days but still facing the same error.

Versions 
node: 14.6.1,
mongoDB: 5.0.19
supertest: "^6.3.3",
jest: "^29.7.0",
mongodb-memory-server: "^8.15.1",
mongoose: "^5.9.15",

Created a new test file for DB connection

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require("mongodb-memory-server");


const dbSetUp = async ()=>{
    let mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create({
        instance: {
           dbName: "platform_db",
           debug: true
        }
     });

    //  await mongod.start();
    
    const uri = mongod.getUri('platform_db');
    console.log(uri)
    mongoose.connect(uri, {
       useNewUrlParser: true,
       useCreateIndex: true,
       useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }, async (err) => {
       if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return false;
       }
       else {
          return mongod;
       }
    });

}

const dbDisconnect = async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  };

module.exports = {
    dbSetUp, dbDisconnect
}
```

In the API files, I'm calling the dbSetup function in the beforeAll() method.

Following error is shown in console

```
Starting the MongoMemoryServer Instance failed, enable debug log for more information. Error:
       GenericMMSError: Instance failed to start within 10000ms
          at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\****\Desktop\testCases\server-apis\node_modules\mongodb-memory-server-core\src\util\MongoInstance.ts:365:21)
          at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
          at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

      at MongoMemoryServer.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/MongoMemoryServer.ts:293:17)
      at node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:169:75
      at __awaiter (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:165:16)
      at node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/MongoMemoryServer.ts:284:68
```